# Background Job Fails with "Current user did not login to the application"

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

using MVC jQuery .NET Core
using Abp [Background Job](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Background-Jobs-And-Workers#introduction)

I have a background job that get Enqueued correctly and I can see the job in the db.

However the logging shows me I'm getting and authorization error (ee below) despite being logged in.  I have the same AbpAuthorize attributes placed on the services and background jobs.

Not sure how to proceed debugging the problem - any suggestions welcome.

SERVICE CODE USING/ENQUEUING THE JOB:

```
   public async Task BulkImportBackground(IList<CreatePracticeDto> inputs)
        {
            await _backgroundJobManager.EnqueueAsync<ImportBulkPracticesBackgroundJob, ImportBulkPracticesBackgroundJobArgs>(
                new ImportBulkPracticesBackgroundJobArgs
                {
                    CreatePracticeDtos = inputs
                });

            _backgroundJobManager.Start();
        }
```

JOB CLASS CODE:

```
using Abp.Authorization;
using Abp.BackgroundJobs;
using Abp.Dependency;
using Abp.Modules;
using Gp.Authorization;
using Gp.Ccre.ImportResult;
using Gp.Ccre.ImportResult.Dtos;
using Gp.Ccre.Practice.Dtos;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Abp.Domain.Uow;

namespace Gp.Ccre.Practice.BackgroundJobs
{
    [DependsOn(
        typeof(IPracticeAppService),
        typeof(IImportResultsAppService))]
    [AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Practices, RequireAllPermissions = false)]
    public class ImportBulkPracticesBackgroundJob : BackgroundJob<ImportBulkPracticesBackgroundJobArgs>, ITransientDependency
    {
        private readonly IPracticeAppService _practiceAppService;
        private readonly IImportResultsAppService _importResultsAppService;

        public ImportBulkPracticesBackgroundJob(IImportResultsAppService importResultsAppService, IPracticeAppService practiceAppService)
        {
            _practiceAppService = practiceAppService;
            _importResultsAppService = importResultsAppService;
        }


        public override void Execute(ImportBulkPracticesBackgroundJobArgs args)
        {

            IList<CreateImportResultDto> createResultsDto = new List<CreateImportResultDto>();
            var k = 0;

            DateTime importedOn = DateTime.Now;

            foreach (CreatePracticeDto createDto in args.CreatePracticeDtos)
            {
                k++;
                try
                {
                    //this correctly automatically ignores 'soft' deleted records.
                    var count = _practiceAppService.GetAllIdName().Result.Count(x => x.Name.Equals(createDto.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        createResultsDto.Add(new CreateImportResultDto
                        {
                            Row = k,
                            Name = createDto.Name,
                            Message = "Already exists. Skipped.",
                            MessageType = AppConsts.ImportMessageType.Warning.ToString(),
                            ImportedOn = importedOn
                        });
                        continue;
                    }

                    // ** GOOGLE MAP API CALL **
                    var coordinatesFound = false; //_practiceAppService.TryGetGeoCodeAddress(createDto);

                    createDto.ImportedOn = importedOn;


                    // ***  SAVE SINGLE ****
                    _practiceAppService.Create(createDto);

                    createResultsDto.Add(new CreateImportResultDto
                    {
                        Row = k,
                        Name = createDto.Name,
                        Message = "Successful.",
                        MessageType = AppConsts.ImportMessageType.Info.ToString(),
                        ImportedOn = importedOn,
                        GoogleMapCoordinatesFound = coordinatesFound
                    });

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    createResultsDto.Add(new CreateImportResultDto
                    {
                        Row = k,
                        Name = createDto.Name,
                        Message = e.Message,
                        MessageType = AppConsts.ImportMessageType.Error.ToString(),
                        ImportedOn = importedOn
                    });
                    continue;
                }
            }

            //*** SAVE RESULTS ***
            foreach (var resultDto in createResultsDto)
            {
                _importResultsAppService.Create(resultDto);
            }

            CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ImportBulkPracticesBackgroundJobArgs
    {
        public IList<CreatePracticeDto> CreatePracticeDtos { get; set; }

    }
}
```

STACK TRACE (partial)

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException: Current user did not login to the application!
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.AuthorizeAsync(IEnumerable`1 authorizeAttributes) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Authorization\AuthorizationHelper.cs:line 43
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.CheckPermissions(MethodInfo methodInfo, Type type) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Authorization\AuthorizationHelper.cs:line 98
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationHelper.AuthorizeAsync(MethodInfo methodInfo, Type type) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Authorization\AuthorizationHelper.cs:line 57
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException(Task task)
   at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(Func`1 action)
   at Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Authorization\AuthorizationInterceptor.cs:line 20
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobManager.TryProcessJob(BackgroundJobInfo jobInfo) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\BackgroundJobs\BackgroundJobManager.cs:line 119
```

Comment: There is no session (and no user) in a background job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by trying to inject a service into the background job.  stick to IRepository and all good.

Comment: an alternative solution would be to create a `domainservice` as opposed to an `applicationservice` and not decorate your `domainservice` with `[AbpAuthorize]`

Comment: you've just made a comment on a thread that is over 2 year old? - things have moved on a bit i think!

Comment: doesn't matter how old the question is if its the first results when i use google and the abp framework hasnt changed that much. in 2 years from now, someone will benefit from my comment.

Comment: @Multinerd - I'm that guy! My problem is i'm getting this issue (same problem, in a batch job), but neither of the services I am using have `[AbpAuthorize]`! (however they _do_ implement `ApplicationService`, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @fullStackChris yes, that could be causing your problem. You want to implement `IDomainService` and `DomainService` instead. https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Domain-Services

Comment: @Multinerd - I figured it out - it was indeed another service called by the batch job that had a higher level authorization endpoint. Luckily in our case, this auth was a mistake and we were able to convert all app service methods used by the batch job with `[RemoteService(false]` and it's running as expected now!